# Linear motion (quiet, variable speed)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, linear, actuator

I want to use a raspberry pi or arduino to create linear motion, back and fourth, my current goal is to make the pushing part for a baby rocker, but also a swing-rocker as a next project

I have looked at linear actuators, but they seem slow and very loud. Ideally I want something like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfmFS7nY2hU, but there is very little information on these and Im suspecting they are out of my price range anyway

The closest hobbyish Ive found is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHdFdw1hLzE or similar, but Id prefer a real product

Iv run out of things to google at "Magnetic Linear Motor", can anyone help me find a product that works with RPi or Arduino or at least a push forward,towards a quiet Linear motion with variable speed

Comment: The 1st is a linear motor with rod shape moving part, but the price of those are prohibitive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_QBl6-_jJU

Comment: A rotary motor driving a crank through a gearbox is probably the simplest option. That also produces harmonic motion, which is what you want for the applications cited.

Comment: @henros : are there any quiet motors? Ideally I want it in one (dev and tested by pros) unit.

Comment: @Marko. Looks nice, I would like one of those. I think it would be to build somethibg like that myself. Di you know where to get one, preferrably hobbyist version.